# Remove Rows from Matrix and Shift

Tags: matlab

I found some information online but not enough to help me solve this issue. I am looping through multiple files and extracting data from the files. It is then stored in an array called `extract`. The problem is that I am doing it in `for` loop and looking for a certain string. If the string does not exist, it still iterates through the loop and increases my counter. So, if I loop through two files and the string I am looking for is not there, but on the third one it is there, then the first row I write to is row 3 and not row 1. I have also attached an image of the first few data elements. I would like to be able to delete the rows that have `[]` and then shift the rows below up. Here is the code and thank you for your time. If there is anything else I can provide please let me know!

```
        function this = extractData(this, xAxis, yAxis)
        s = dir('*.txt'); % Gather all text files

        for i=1:length(s) % Loop through and gather data until last element of strcuct
            j = 1;
            fid = s(i).name; % Open file in read-only mode
            this = this.readDataFromFile(fid);
            if ~contains(this.metaData(:,1), xAxis)
                continue;
            end
            x = this.metaData(find(contains(this.metaData(:,1), xAxis)),3);
            this.extract{i,j} = x;
            j = j+1;
            y = this.metaData(find(contains(this.metaData, yAxis)),3); %#ok<*FNDSB>
            this.extract(i,j) = y;
        end %for

        xAxis = strrep(xAxis, ' ', '_'); % For file formatting
        yAxis = strrep(yAxis, ' ', '_');
        this.colLabels = {xAxis, yAxis};

        % Write it all to a file 
       fileName = 'myTestFile.txt'
       filepath = cd;
       file = fullfile(filepath, fileName);
       fid = fopen(file, 'w');
       if fid == -1
           error ('Cannot open file for writing: %s', file);
       end

       % File must denote where meta-data and data begin
       fprintf(fid, '%-72s', '=============================meta data============================='); 
       fprintf(fid, '\n');
       for row=1:size(this.extract,1)
           for col=1:size(this.extract,2)
                fprintf(fid, '%s', this.extract{row,col});
           end
           fprintf(fid, '\n');
       end %for
        fclose(fid);               
    end %extractData
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for a loop logic like this?

```
k = 1;
for i=1:length(s)
    fid = s(i).name;
    %...
    if %...
        continue;
    end
    this.extract{k,j} = %...
    k = k + 1;
end
```

Here we're simply decoupling the index `i` that indicates which file to read from, from the index `k` that indicates which row in the output matrix to write to.

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you.

Comment: I have another issue. I can totally write another question, but it seems quite simple. The issue is that `fprintf` statement: when I hit that it errors out, "function not defined for cell inputs." Makes enough sense on the face, but I cannot figure out what in the world is going on. I go through the same loop logic elsewhere in the code and it works just fine with a cell array; so, I am curious if the matter is in the loop you corrected above where I define each index. I changed those to: `this.extract(k,j) = x;` and `this.extract(k,j) = y;`. This was an issue before, too. Ideas?

Comment: @DymaxionFuller: If `this.metaData` is a cell array, then `x` will also be a cell array, and indeed you need to do `this.extract(...)=x`. The alternative is `this.extract{...}=x{1}`. That is, assign a cell to a cell, or the contents of a cell to the contents of a cell. Does that explanation make sense?

Comment: `this.metaData` is, indeed, a cell array. In fact, that is the cell array that I used `fprintf`on earlier in the code. So why won't `fprintf` work? Also, `this.extract(k,j) = x;` spits out: "Conversion to double from cell is not possible." I understand what these errors mean, but I can't see why I receive them when I effectively use the same functionality and logic on another cell array. (P.S. I know it's never the code).

Comment: @Dymaxion: Is `this.extract` initialized? Maybe you need to do `this.extract={}` at the top of the function. Note that [`fprintf` doesn't accept a cell array](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html#btf8xsy-1-A1An).

Comment: Yes, this worked. I tried this earlier, but failed to create a new instance of the object! I am learning :) Thanks for the help.